# Passing a varying number of macro arguments as a string in System Verilog

Tags: macros, arguments, system-verilog, test-bench

I have an existing code that uses some macro definitions in order to display messages from my test cases.  I want to change the implementation of these macros, however, as these macros are extensively used in already existing testcases, I am looking to reimplement their functionality witout having to modify how the macros are used.

Currently the macros are difined as such:

```
`define My_Info         $write("INFO:"); $display
`define My_Error        $write("ERROR:"); $display
```

In the testcases, example calls of these macros include:

```
`My_Info("This is an info message with arguments %0d, %0d, and %0d", var1, var2, var3);
`My_Info("My_ID",  $psprintf("ID    : %s", var4));
`My_Error("Failed to open file: %s ", fname);
```

Currently `$display`, displays the messages in the brakets.

What I want to do is to define the macros in a way that these messages in the brakets of the macro calls could be passed as a string argument to a function (for example the function  `my_msg(msg)` where `msg` is a string and `my_msg` is a function that formats and returns this string to the log file.
My issue is, because in the testcases the macro calls have varying number of arguments as seen in the example above, I am not sure how to define the macros in a universal way.

Currenlty my solution is to define the macros like:

```
`define My_Info(string=" ", var1= , var2= , var3= , var4= )       my_msg($sformat(s,var1, var2, var3, var4)
```

But this relies on a finite number of arguments (in this case 5).

Is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround the lack of varying numbers of macro arguments by requiring an extra set of ()'s.

```
module top;
  
  `define my_error(msg) begin $error({"My ID:",$sformatf msg}); end
  
  int a,b;
  
  initial begin
    `my_error( ("hello") )
    `my_error( ("A = %0d B = %0d", a,b) )
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Is this support do we have in verilog-2005 also ?

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMeda, Macros are poorly defined in Verilog. This works in the _Verilog-mode_ of tools that also support SystemVerilog.